# Finding/locating a clickable text by xpath in div/span format

Tags: python, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I used the following line to click the Availability Grid button, but it failed to locate the element.
Class Sarsa-button-content is used everywhere so, I added text together to make it unique. However, it couldn't find it. What am I missing?

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='sarsa-button-content']/span[text()='Availability Grid']"))).click()
```

```
 <div class="sticky-top-wrapper" style="top: 80px;">
  <div class="site-filter-container" id="site-filter-container">
    <a data-component="Button" class="sarsa-button view-by-availability-grid--button-tracker sarsa-button-primary sarsa-button-sm" href="/site/123456/availability">
      <span class="sarsa-button-inner-wrapper">
        <span class="sarsa-button-content">Availability Grid</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your xpath is wrong, try this:

```
//span[contains(@class, 'sarsa-button-content') and text() = 'Availability Grid']
```

Comment: I tried it, but I couldn't find the element. so, I used the absolute xpath instead.
thanks for your help.                                                        
This one did not work...                                                           
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'sarsa-button-content') and text() = 'Availability Grid']"))).click()
the absolute xpath worked..                        
    grid = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/a")
    grid.click()